# Spark udf to create new columns from existing column, along with using group by

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I have a dataframe with following columns: group_id, gender and height.

group_id and height are Int.
gender is string.

```
group_id| gender|height
 1      |  F    |  52
 1      |  F    |  53
 1      |  F    |  58 
 1      |  M    |  55
 1      |  M    |  59
 2      |  F    |  50
 2      |  M    |  60
 2      |  M    |  61
 2      |  M    |  64
```

I would like to group by group_id, gender and height_range
The height ranges can be anything, but are predefined- example 48-50, 51-58,58-64 etc.
For simplicity here I am considering increments of 5 inches: 50-54, 55-59, 60-64.

Expected output:

```
group_id | gender | height_low | height_high | count
   1     | F      |    50      |    54       |   2
   1     | F      |    55      |    59       |   1
   1     | M      |    55      |    59       |   2
   2     | F      |    50      |    54       |   1
   2     | M      |    60      |    64       |   3
```

I tried using sum(when). That didn't help much to get low and high values.
Other way I could think of was to use a hive udf 2 times, once to populate height_low with various conditions in when clause and another time to populate height_high.
I would like to know if there is a way to populate both of these at the same time since its the same check I need to perform.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `floor` (rounding-down) of the result of `height / 5` as the key for grouping (along with the other columns), then calculate the `height_low` and `height_high` if necessary:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import spark.implicits._

val result = df.groupBy($"group_id", $"gender", floor($"height" / 5) * 5 as "height_low")
  .count()
  .withColumn("height_high", $"height_low" + 4)
```

**EDIT**: the more general case, where ranges aren't necessarily of a constant size, can indeed be solved using a UDF that returns a tuple representing the range:

```
// For a set of ranges, given as an ordered list of range lower bounds:
val rangeLowerBoundaries = List(50, 55, 60, 65) // ordered!

// create UDF for finding the range, returns a tuple of (start, end), 
// uses 0 and MaxValue as edges of first and last range, respectively:
val findMatchingRange = udf[(Int, Int), Int] { height => (
  rangeLowerBoundaries.filter(_ <= height).lastOption.getOrElse(0),
  rangeLowerBoundaries.find(_ > height).getOrElse(Int.MaxValue) - 1
)}

// group by UDF and then select and rename tuple's elements:
val result = df.groupBy($"group_id", $"gender", findMatchingRange($"height") as "range")
  .count()
  .select($"group_id", $"gender", $"range._1" as "height_low", $"range._2" as "height_high", $"count")
  .show(false)

result.show(false)
// +--------+------+----------+-----------+-----+
// |group_id|gender|height_low|height_high|count|
// +--------+------+----------+-----------+-----+
// |1       |F     |55        |59         |1    |
// |2       |M     |60        |64         |3    |
// |2       |F     |50        |54         |1    |
// |1       |M     |55        |59         |2    |
// |1       |F     |50        |54         |2    |
// +--------+------+----------+-----------+-----+
```